# Скрипт для отображения текстуры внутри сферы не работает

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Нашел C# скрипт шейдера (Unity) для отображения текстуры на внутренней поверхности сферы с возможностью изменить тайлинг. Почему-то после применения шейдера нельзя добавить текстуру, объект становится розовым.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что выдает консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шейдер отсюда: https://medium.com/@verochan/how-to-make-a-360%C2%BA-image-viewer-with-unity3d-b1aa9f99cabb

Скрипт очень нужен, как это можно исправить?
Заранее большое спасибо!

```
Shader “Unlit/Pano360Shader”
{
Properties
{
_MainTex (“Base (RGB)”, 2D) = “white” {}
_Color (“Main Color”, Color) = (1,1,1,0.5)
}
SubShader 
{
Tags { “RenderType” = “Opaque” }
//This is used to print the texture inside of the sphere
Cull Front
CGPROGRAM
#pragma surface surf SimpleLambert
half4 LightingSimpleLambert (SurfaceOutput s, half3 lightDir, half atten)
{
half4 c;
c.rgb = s.Albedo;
return c;
}

sampler2D _MainTex;
struct Input
{
float2 uv_MainTex;
float4 myColor : COLOR;
};

fixed3 _Color;
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o)
{
//This is used to mirror the image correctly when printing it inside of the sphere
IN.uv_MainTex.x = 1 — IN.uv_MainTex.x;
fixed3 result = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex)*_Color;
o.Albedo = result.rgb;
o.Alpha = 1;
}
ENDCG
}
Fallback “Diffuse”
}
```

Comment: Выдели шейдер в проекте, там скорей всего ошибка компиляции, если есть, то в студию... так погоди, что c# скрипт шейдера? Ты этот код в .cs скрипт положил? Или в .shader?

Comment: @Xumera_hZ очно, спасибо, добавил в описание!

Comment: Кавычки могут быть.

Comment: @ValeraKvip Добавил } в конце и ошибки из консоли исчезли но проблема осталась.

Comment: @Xumera_hZ Добавил } в конце и ошибки из консоли исчезли но проблема осталась.

Comment: @Rumata Там же пишет shader is not supported on this gpu. Выдели шейдер если в окне инспектора нет ошибок компиляции, нажми compile и скинь код, который он покажет

Comment: @Xumera_hZ Спасибо! Вот что получилось:

Comment: @Xumera_hZ // Compiled shader for PC, Mac & Linux Standalone

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// 
// NOTE: This is *not* a valid shader file, the contents are provided just
// for information and for debugging purposes only.
// 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Skipping shader variants that would not be included into build of current scene.

Shader "" {
}

Comment: @Xumera_hZ выделено цветом только   
Shader "" {
}

Comment: @Xumera_hZ Добавил скриншоты

Answer (score 0):

Кароче, все ковычки поменяй вручную, в строке "`IN.uv_MainTex.x = 1 — IN.uv_MainTex.x;`", вместо '—' ставь '-'. И впредь не копипасть, а вбей вручную. И будет тебе счастье